Play in rear mech
Came off my bike a while back, noticed the indexing was off and drivetrain worn, so replaced the lot. Indexing still off no matter how well I adjust. Inspect rear mech, it's noticably bent, can't easily tell if it's just hanger, but mech also has noticeable play around the bolt, even though the bolt is tight. It's a Shimano sora 9 speed fwiw.


Am planning to take to LBS soon, but they're very busy atm so hoping there may be a home solution (or at least to narrow down the problems for them to fix it quickly). I'm thinking to properly check if the hanger is bent (unsure how atm), remove mech and check any bushings/fittings for obvious damage. Any other ideas? Am I barking up the wrong tree and the mech is toast? Is there some obvious way to adjust this that I've missed?

The derailleur should rotate around the bolt, but minimal lateral play.
Just eyeballing your photo, it looks like the derailleur is dead-on with dropout, but the cassette is obviously not parallel. The problem would be in your rear axle, QR, or the seating on the side.

There's substantial lateral play on the bolt, much more than on a similar-ish bike from the same brand, and enough to make the mech in line with the cassette. There's also a noticeable scrape on the derailleur from my fall. Pretty sure the axle is fine, the wheel is definitely seated fine, not sure what you mean by QR. Edit: quick release, okay yeah not this either thanks

There's a pretty handy shade-three-mechanic hack. You take a front wheel and thread the front axle into the derailleur hanger threads, the threads are the same. The rim gives you a very large plane that is perpendicular to the derailleur hanger threads and from there it should already be easy to tell if the derailleur is bent or not.

If there's a bunch of lateral play as you describe, you probably did damage something during the crash. I'd imagine you need a new derailleur. Threading the front wheel into the hanger to check its straightness is not a bad idea to see if the hanger is okay or not.

Thanks folks, lbs squeezed me in for a morning thankfully, otherwise it was a few weeks wait. was mainly massively bent hanger, some slight play in the axle but tightened out.

Shimano usually has a spring in the upper pivot. I imagine the end of the spring might not be sitting in its hole and thereby preventing the bolt from tightening to the right depth.
Let us know what happens.
